# Parameters of a Statistical Distribution

Tags: distributions

Any statistical distribution is described in terms of shape, scale and location parameters. But what do these parameters mean, geometrically, statistically and for a layman with minimum statistical knowledge?

I have explored wikipedia and still, this doubt continues to exist.

Answer (score 7):

Some technicalities to complement @vinux's answer:

If you have a density $f_X(\cdot)$ for a random variable $X$ where
$$f_X\left(x;\theta,\phi;\vec\xi\right)=\tfrac{1}{\phi}f_X\left(\frac{x-\theta}{\phi};0,1;\vec\xi\right)$$
then $\theta$, $\phi$, & $\vec\xi$ are location, scale, & shape parameters respectively.

Location parameters only shift the density, changing its mean (if it has one) & other measures of central tendency, but no higher moments.

Scale parameters only stretch the density, changing its variance (if it has one) & other measures of dispersion, & the mean when $\newcommand{\ex}{\operatorname{E}}\ex X\neq\theta$, but no higher moments.

Shape parameters change the shape of the density, perhaps stretching or shifting too, so may change any moments. They tend to get called 'shape' parameters only in contrast to location & scale parameters; e.g. the Weibull distribution has scale & shape parameters but no-one talks about the shape parameter of the Poisson distribution (though they do about the two shape parameters of the beta distribution).

It's perhaps worth emphasizing @Nick's point that a parameter's being equal to the expectation of the random variable  doesn't imply that it's a location parameter: $$\psi=\ex{X} \quad \not\Rightarrow \quad f_X\left(x;\psi\right)=f_X\left(x-\psi;0\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

The names of the parameters are suggestive. Location, and scale parameters are associated with central tendency, dispersion respectively. For eg: If you change location parameters, mostly it change only the central tendency measures.

Try this online tool. [Distributions](http://socr.ucla.edu/htmls/SOCR_Distributions.html)

See how the distribution changes for different values of parameters. You could try this with generalized extreme value distribution.

Not all standard distributions have all three parameters. Some distributions have only one or two of the parameters (eg: gamma distribution-shape and scale parameters)

Comment: Shape is associated not just with skew, but with anything that isn't to do with central tendency or dispersion; a shape parameter might well affect higher moments. It's any parameter that isn't a location or scale parameter. And cross out 'mostly' in the second sentence unless you can think of an exception.

Comment: @Scortchi Agreed on "shape". Vinux: A simple example is the Poisson. Change the mean and you change variance, skewness, kurtosis, ... It is not clear whether you regard such linked changes as usual or exceptional.

Comment: @Nick: But would you call the mean of the Poisson  a location parameter? I wouldn't. Same goes for the mean of the exponential distribution - it's a scale parameter.

Comment: I guess that mathematical statisticians have invariance and equivariance criteria for different kinds of parameter. I am reacting to @Vinux's line that location indicates central tendency and the idea that location and central tendency are the same ballpark. That's probably loose at best by mathematical standards, but it's a data analytic view.

Comment: Would it be right to say that for a location parameter $\theta$ the density $f(x;\theta)=f(x-\theta;0)$ and changing it only changes the mean; while for a scale parameter $\phi$ the density $f(x;\phi)=\frac{f(\frac{x}{\phi};1)}{\phi}$ and changing it only changes the variance & perhaps the mean?

Comment: I think the question is very broad. I am not sure about  any standard definition for shape in distribution context. I was trying to give a layman's picture.

Comment: Fair enough - but 'skewness' is even less a layman's term than 'shape'. Location parameters *shift*, scale parameters *stretch*, and shape parameters change the *shape*.

Comment: @Scortchi You are right. I should not associate shape with skewness. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Scortchi The lay use of "skewed" is increasingly as meaning "biased", as in "the results are skewed by including too many people of type X". It may have been around for some time, but I've noticed it more recently. I haven't noticed "skewness" as a synonym for "bias".

Comment: Thanks for clearing the geometric way of explaining the doubts. I wish to have clarity on the statistical idea. A standard reference with a detailed explanation would be of great help. A confusion regarding the scale and the shape exists though !