# Order Statistics

Tags: order-statistics

What is the motivation behind the use of order statistics in parameter estimation. In a very general sense, the first order statistic is considered to be an initial estimate to the location parameter. I wonder, how this would be possible. A layman based explanation would help.

Comment: Who considers the first order statistic to be a good initial estimate of a location parameter, & in what context? It would certainly be a very odd one for most situations.

Comment: @Scortchi Whenever an iterative procedure is being used for parameter estimation, as the initial value for the location parameter is generally taken to be either the first order statistic, or a linear combination of the first few order statistic

Comment: Certainly not true in general. Are you thinking of say a three-parameter Weibull model?

Comment: I wonder, Vani, whether we might have a communication problem here.  Most people would understand a "first order statistic" to be the minimum (or sometimes the maximum) of a dataset.  I hope it's obvious that is a terrible estimate of a location parameter except under very special assumptions such as those described in Scortchi's answer.  Would you perhaps have something else in mind here, such as the median?  Could you clarify this point?

Comment: OP: please clarify the meaning of your question. It seems like you must either be misusing some terms or that you refer to a very particular context; in either case you can't hope for a very satisfying answer until the miscommunication is dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

The motivations for the use of an order statistic as an estimator are no different from the [motivations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/how-do-i-know-which-method-of-parameter-estimation-to-choose) for the use of any statistic as an estimator. For example, if you want to estimate the mean $\mu$ of a continuous uniform distribution from $0$ to $2\mu$, the sample maximum is the complete [sufficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/sufficient-statistics-for-layman) statistic for $\mu$, so both the [maximum-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/maximum-likelihood/info) & the uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimators are based on it. If you want to estimate the mean $\theta$ of a normal distribution, the sample mean is the complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$, so both the maximum-likelihood & the uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimators are based on it.

It's not true in general that the first order statistic is a good estimator of a  [location parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72806/parameters-of-a-statistical-distribution) (in any reasonable sense of 'good'). Recall the mean of a normal distribution is a location parameter— in this case the sample minimum would not even be a [consistent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/what-is-the-difference-between-a-consistent-estimator-and-an-unbiased-estimator) estimator. You've perhaps come across location parameters added to distributions like the Weibull, whose two-parameter version has a lower bound at zero. In cases like this the sample minimum is a consistent estimator of the population minimum, & I daresay a decent starting point for fitting algorithms.

Comment: I guess its about 'first order' approximations of something, not about order statistics.

Comment: @Michael: Might be, but something in the phrasing of the comment triggers old memories of reliability analysis & shifted failure-time distributions.